# black screen after nvidia driver installation after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, ubuntu-drivers, gpu-driver

after upgrading my machine to 18.04 from 16.04 I noticed that my Nvidia driver is no longer installed and after I reinstalled the driver I'm getting a black screen I've got such a problem before and fixed it with manually installing the Nvidia driver instead of using autoinstall or apt-get install Nvidia (number goes here).
I've tried all the method of installation mentioned [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)
and read almost all topic about this problem on askubuntu, its almost 2 weeks now and I'm unable to find a solution to this problem

### information you might need

```
lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] (rev a1)

ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000013C2sv00001458sd0000367Abc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM204 [GeForce GTX 970]
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

nvidia-detector 
none

sudo lshw -numeric -C display
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] [10DE:13C2]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f2000000-f2ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f3000000-f307ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:412]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f3400000-f37fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)

##glxinfo -B
name of display: :1
display: :1  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 18.2.8
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 15904MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.2.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.2.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00

##uname -a 
Linux LeLouch 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### edit i fixed the problem by updating the kernel

i've spent 3 weeks now with this and the problem was the grub boot loader needed to be updated after the linux-header update i used update-grub every time but i fail to notice that the main grub boot loader was on another distro so i needed to update that grub and that fixed my problem.
all thanks to @BarBar1234

Comment: when does the black screen appears? during boot, after boot? or else?

Comment: black screen appears after I select Ubuntu from the grub and a few seconds later the keyboard num pad light start working  which means ubuntu has loaded  but i can see nothing other than a black screen even ctrl + alt + f1 / f2 -->  f12 goes no where

Comment: 16.04 -> 18.04 upgrades rarely run smooth. I can't get mine working as well. Consider a fresh install.

Comment: Upgrades typically want you to disable 3rd party repos.  If you did (the graphics ppa?), did you re-enable them, since 415 is not in the standard repos.

Comment: @Pilot6 fresh install is not an option

Comment: @ubfan1 yes I did re-enable them and tried with and without the repo auto and manual install and getting always the same problem

Comment: Check all files in /etc/modprobe.d for  blacklist nvidia lines (except OK to blacklist nvidiafb) -- remove them if any.  What happens when you add the nvidia driver with modprobe nvidia (presuming you have the driver, and it's not getting used)? Post the output of lsmod | grep nvi  (four nvidia... modules expected).  Did you ever try booting an older kernel?

Comment: I would try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

disable Secure Boot in BIOS, as Secure Boot blocks the nvidia modules from being loaded in this case.

Comment: found secure boot already disabled

Comment: Ok, and have you tried the grub option `nouveau.modeset=0` already as well?

Comment: YES , i used that to  uninstall all the nvidia drivers and log back to my desktop

Comment: Ok, could you provide the printout of `glxinfo -B` when you have modeset set to zero. I can't recall if glxinfo is already included, but if not you should be able to get it from the main repo. Also, please add `uname -a` output for additional reference

Comment: thanks for the reply nouveau.modeset=0 didn't help at all but i sed nomodeset=0 to go back to desktop and i've updated what you asked for

Comment: Ok, I see that you have a whole selection of drivers you attempted to use, can you remove all nvidia drivers, and load only the `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` one and then try the `nouveau.modeset=0` grub parameter. also make sure your linux-headers are up to date!

Comment: after I removed all Nvidia driver and made sure I was booting properly using nouveau I tried  nouveau.modeset=0 on the grub parameter and went back to the same black screen .

Comment: Sorry, I edited the last comment I posted right after posting, but didnt realize there was only a 5 min window for editing and it didnt get updated. The nouveau.modeset=0 will of course cause a black screen when nouveau is the only nvidia driver in use. MY updated comment went something like this: purge all propriatary drivers and use nouvedau and test reboot, then re-check to make sure that the `lshw -numeric -C` now lists driver=nouveau in the line with `configuration: latency` and `glxinfo -B` updates the driver information as well.

Comment: However, I just noticed the last part of the shell output you provided namely `$uname -a` . How do you have such an outdated kernel version if running Ubuntu 18.04? The 18.04 uses 4.15 kernel version. Please post output of `$sudo apt search linux-headers-$(uname -r)` because your headers seem very outdated and your gpu is a recent model. I would just proceed with header update and then let dkms build the nvidia driver accordingly:  `$sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-//') nvidia-driver`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90290/discussion-between-lelouch-and-barbar1234).

Answer (score 0):

I tried countless solutions found on the internet, the only thing that worked for me was to:

- backup `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.old`
- similarly backup `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory, if it exists
- and then `cp -r /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d /etc/X11/`